# Trying to open a .avi; nothing can recognise it

Tags: video, encoding, movie

I am trying to watch an .avi, and for some reason nothing can open it.
I've tried using DivX Player, QuickTime Player, VLC, AirParrot 2, Kodi 18.0.rc5, IINA, Elmedia player, and (converting it in) Handbrake without any sucess. I do have .z codec files, but I can't open them with DivX Player. Does anyone have any ideas on how to open this .avi, or how to install the codec?

macOS Sierra

Comment: You could try https://iina.io/

Comment: It's possible that it is damaged and can't be played, have you tried IINA? It's brand new and supposedly quite good https://iina.io/. Failing all of that try converting it to any other format with Handbrake. If that fails the file is damaged.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried IINA, it can’t open it either. Trying Handbrake now

Comment: Handbrake gives me `[08:50:48] scan: unrecognized file type
[08:50:48] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
[08:50:48] macgui: ScanCore scan done`

Comment: @Steve Chambers is there any way to install the codec?

Comment: Update: I’ve opened the .z codec with B1FreeArchiver, unzipped the .zip that created, and now have a suspicous looking .app

Comment: Unfortunately no. Look at discussions around FFMPEG on the Mac, there might be some knowledgable people there that can help with more experience along these lines.